# Merge two vectors with alternate locations

Tags: python, numpy

I have:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.asarray([1,3,5,7,9])
B = np.asarray([2,4,6,8,10])
```

I want to create:

```
C = np.asarray([1,2,3, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

Is there a better way to do than to run a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can the *stack* arrays vertically using [`vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html#numpy.vstack), *transpose* and then [`ravel`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
>>> A = np.asarray([1,3,5,7,9])
>>> B = np.asarray([2,4,6,8,10])
>>> C = np.vstack((A, B)).T.ravel()
>>> C
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

Comment: Nice approach. I've just sorted the stacked lists, not that original ...

Comment: I think the sorting will give wrong results in other cases.

Comment: Then his/her question is not clear. Want to sort or what ?

Comment: Take values in alternation from two arrays to create a third array

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
import numpy as np
A = np.asarray([1,3,5,7,9])
B = np.asarray([2,4,6,8,10])

C = np.sort(np.hstack((A,B)))
#array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```